# order by column in a group by aggregate function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have venues and venues have many items. I want to get the latest item per venue. To return the latest item for each venue in a single query, I can use the max aggregate function with group by:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :newest_items, -> (venue_ids) {
    select('max(items.id) as id, venue_id').joins(:venue).where('venues.id IN (?)', venue_ids).group(:venue_id)
  }
end
```

The resulting sql:

```
Item.newest_items(Venue.pluck(:id)).to_sql 
 => "SELECT max(items.id) as id, venue_id FROM \"items\" 
    INNER JOIN \"venues\" ON \"venues\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"venue_id\" 
    WHERE (venues.id IN (1,2,3)) 
    GROUP BY \"items\".\"venue_id\""
```

So I have the latest item for each venue. BUT with that result, I want to sort the results by the date they were created.

If I had an order by clause:

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :newest_items, -> (venue_ids) {
    select('max(items.id) as id, venue_id')
    .joins(:venue).where('venues.id IN (?)', venue_ids)
    .group(:venue_id).order('items.created_at desc')
  }
end
```

The sql:

```
Item.close_by_items(Venue.pluck(:id)).to_sql
=> "SELECT max(items.id) as id, venue_id 
    FROM \"items\" INNER JOIN \"venues\" ON \"venues\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"venue_id\" 
    WHERE (venues.id IN (1,2,3)) 
    GROUP BY \"items\".\"venue_id\" 
    ORDER BY items.created_at desc"
```

I get the error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "items.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Why must created_at appear in GROUP BY clause or be used in the aggregate function? All I want to do is order the results of the group by clause by the created_at time.

Comment: you can't `order by` a column that isn't being selected.

Comment: @vkp even if it is added to select statement, the error is the same: column "items.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: yes..if you aren't aggregating it, it should be in `group by`.

Comment: @vkp why? I don't understand why it is needed in group by. I am trying to order the results of the group by.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a single item per venue can use `DISTINCT ON` instead of grouping.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.newest_items(*venues)
    select('DISTINCT ON(items.venue_id), items.*')
      .where(venue_id: *venues)
      .order('items.created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Comment: When I said 'latest item' in my question, I mean the item with the maximum id. DISTINCT ON is similar to MAX?

Comment: No not really. `DISTINCT ON(items.venue_id)` means that only one row per  `items.venue_id` will be returned by the query. I don't really get why you are so adamant on using the id to sort. Sorting by `items.created_at` will give you the last created row anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is putting `ORDER` inside a subquery, something like this should work as you expect:

```
Item.close_by_items(Venue.pluck(:id)).to_sql
=> "SELECT max(sub.id) as id, sub.venue_id FROM (SELECT items.id, venue_id 
    FROM \"items\" INNER JOIN \"venues\" ON \"venues\".\"id\" = \"items\".\"venue_id\" 
    WHERE (venues.id IN (1,2,3)) ORDER BY items.created_at desc") AS sub
    GROUP BY \"sub\".\"venue_id\"
```